# Python handle API

Tags: python, json, api, data

Eu quero usar a seguinte resposta de API:
https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20160228/BTC/USD

Depois quero dividi-la em blocos assim:
[1456617600,434.3867,434.3867,433.781,433.781,4.15450000]
e metê-la numa lista para conseguir trabalhar com os dados.

Eu estava a fazer assim mas não está a funcionar:

```
 r=requests.get('https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20160228/BTC/USD')
    r= json.loads(r.text)
    list= []
    for row in r:
        list.append(row)
```

Comment: Mariana, este é o [pt.so]. Você pode clicar [edit] e traduzir sua pergunta ou, se preferir, pode postá-la no [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando usas

```
r = json.loads(r.text)
```

o `json` vai transformar o texto que veio do `request` num dicionário com duas chaves apenas, `time` e `data1m`.

Os blocos de que falas estão sob a chave `data1m`, portanto vais ter de os ir buscar aí. O único problema é que fazer

```
r["data1m"]
```

devolve uma `string` (podes verificar com `type(r["data1m"])`)

portanto vais ter de transformar também essa `string` numa lista com que possas trabalhar. Podes fazer isso se usares o `json.loads` de novo:

```
r = requests.get('https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20160228/BTC/USD')
r = json.loads(r.text)
lista = json.loads(r["data1m"])
```

Neste ponto, `lista` já é uma lista cujas entradas são os blocos de que falas. Por exemplo,

```
lista[0]
```

devolve

```
[1456617600, 434.3867, 434.3867, 433.781, 433.781, 4.1545]
```